# Java Live Command line

Tags: java, shell

Is there a library or way to have a live command line that instead of printing out each line works like a graphics library where you can just update one element if it has changed?

Example of usage would be to display current time. Instead of refreshing the cmd and appending more things to it, you just update the current time object and reprint or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, although it is not 100% pure Java (despite of what the web page says):

http://code.google.com/p/lanterna/

It works very well and it is easy to use. Development is a bit slow but the developer does answer questions. I recommend checking the Terminal Layer, which is perhaps what you need.

Comment: It is very interesting but I was looking for a pure command line approach rather than a GUI. Just so that you can run it from the command line through ssh.

Comment: You can run that through ssh. The tool can generate pure text interface just like curses. The Terminal Layer can position the cursor anywhere and let you put whatever letter.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is because there is a GUI layer that creates windows for you. You can even ask the Windows to be Swing. But if you stick to the Terminal Layer, everything is pure command line, compatible with ssh etc.

Comment: I will take a deeper look into it and let you know.